# Disable user's physical keyboard in <p:keyboard>

Tags: jsf, primefaces, keyboard

Is there a way I can make the input from `<p:keyboard>` not work with the user's physical keyboard? I only want the input to be introduced by using the UI keyboard, not the real one for security purposes.

Comment: Then don't provide an editable input type field. Just place the keyboard there and provide visual feedback with an `<h:outputText/>` or something

Comment: @kolossus: while he did indeed not explicitly mention it, OP is clearly talking about `<p:keyboard>`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `keypadonly="true"` attribute like this :

```
<p:keyboard keypadOnly="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried `readonly="true"` and worked, try use this way.